# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the relation "test_id" does not exist. SQL state: 42883

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I can not retrieve the id from the "test" table after saving it in postgresql by pgadmin4:

Here the create script generated by pgadmi4 of the table "test":

```
CREATE TABLE school.test
(
    test_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('school.test_test_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE school.test
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Here the code to insert the values to the "test" table thourgh JDBC:

```
        Connection conn = pstgConn.dbConnection();
        String query = "INSERT INTO school.test(name) VALUES (?)";
        try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
            pst.setString(1, "anything");
            pst.executeUpdate();
            //Get Sequential number of the table
            getSerialNum(conn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here the function to get the last SerialNumber of the affected table:

```
public void getSerialNum(Connection connection) {
        int serialNum = 0;
        try {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

            // get the postgresql serial field value with this query
            String query = "select currval('test_id')";

            ResultSet rs;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if (rs.next()) {
                serialNum = rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("serialNum = " + serialNum);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I have tried to run isolately by pdgadmin console with the same results.

Here the results:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: the relation "test_id" does not exist
  Position : 16
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
    at com.cgi.training.javase.school.dao.testDAO.getSerialNum(testDAO.java:45)
    at com.cgi.training.javase.school.dao.testDAO.main(testDAO.java:21)

Comment: Your sequence is named `test_test_id_seq` but you are passing the name `test_id` to the call of `currval()`

Comment: you right. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Response from @a_horse_with_no_name: Your sequence is named test_test_id_seq but you are passing the name test_id to the call of currval() – a_horse_with_no_name